# exc_bad_access after return cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am picking image from imagePickerController & making it resize to 80X80 & displaying in table.

below is code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]

                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
      }

     photobj= [appD.array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"photoobj=%@",photobj);
    cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,80);
    cell.imageView.tag=2000+indexPath.row;

    UIImage *img1=[[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:photobj.imgdata]autorelease];
    NSLog(@"frame=%f",img1.size.width);
   // img1=[UIImage imageWithData:photobj.imgdata];
    cell.imageView.image=img1;
    NSLog(@"frame=%@",cell.imageView.image);

    return cell;//after this , crash
}
```

after return cell it crashes if i call below image resize method

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImageToSize:(CGSize)targetSize withImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = img;

    UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];

    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // make image center aligned
        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
   thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil)
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");

    return newImage ;
}
```

below is the code where i am calling above method
 UIImage *imageEdited = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

```
self.img_imageView2.image=[self resizeImageToSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80) withImage:imageEdited   ]; 
    photobj=[[PhotoObject alloc]init];

    photobj.imgdata=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img_imageView2.image, 0.9);
    [appD.array1 addObject:photobj];
```

if i bypasses this imageresizing method then it works fine, i am not getting exactly what is the problem?

Comment: What is `imageEdited`?

Comment: it is just image taken from imagepickercontroller

Comment: Oh, so what is `img1` in your cell creation method?

Comment: i have added imageEdit line

Comment: i have saved resized image in array in one viewController & taking it in another viewController's cell creation method i.e. img1 taking from that array

Comment: it's EXC_BAD_ACCESS not exe_bad_access

Comment: Wait a second, I see an `autorelease` are you not using ARC??

Comment: without autorelease also same problem

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that it was a problem to use autorelease.  However, as good practice you should retain your `img` argument at the start of resize, and release it at the end.  Also if possible get the line that it is crashing on by setting an exception breakpoint.

Comment: How does your property declaration of 'imgData' in the class 'PhotoObject' look like?

Comment: @interface PhotoObject : NSObject
{
     NSData *imgdata;
    NSMutableArray *imagearray;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSData *imgdata;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *imagearray;

Comment: The properties look valid! Is "could not scale image" printed out before the crash?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a UIImageView and adding it to the cell rather than using cell.imageView
I would also set it within the if statement and recall it from the tag using the else statement. Otherwise it will be recreated everytime it appears in the view.

Try

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UIImageView *myImageView;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]

            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    myImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)] autorelease];
    myImageView.tag = 2000+indexPath.row;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];

  }
  else
  {
       myImageView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2000+indexPath.row];
  }

 photobj= [appD.array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"photoobj=%@",photobj);


UIImage *img1=[[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:photobj.imgdata]autorelease];
NSLog(@"frame=%f",img1.size.width);

myImageView.image = img1;



  NSLog(@"frame=%@", imageView.image);

return cell;
}
```

I use the following code for image resize. You would just need to tweak it a bit to take your size parameters and do the scaling

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
image.image = img;



[self _resizeImage];

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];




}



//function that is called by the image picker to resize the image for passing from one view to the next
- (void) _resizeImage {
NSInteger height;
NSInteger width;
height = 280;
width = 280;

CGImageRef imageRef = [image.image CGImage];
CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone) {
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
}

CGContextRef bitmap;

if (image.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || image.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

}
else {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, height, width, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

}

if (image.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, radians(90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, 0, -height);
}
else if (image.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, radians(-90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, -width, 0);
}
else if (image.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {

}
else if (image.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, width, height);
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, radians(-180.));
}


CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);      


CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceInfo);
CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);
thisCopyImage = result;
bgImage.image = thisCopyImage;

}
```

Comment: I have added some image resize code above as that seems to be what is causing yours to crash, you will need to rewrite it a bit to work with your inputs but the basics are there for taking an image from the camera and resizing it.